# multiplying the output of a linear regression with a constant in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction, confidence-interval

I ran a regression with the goal of predicting the sales given 21 TVs and 75radios. This prediction is for on store. However, my goal is to predict this for 90 stores.

```
europet.2 = lm(sales ~ 1 + tv + radio, data=A2)
    summary(europet.2, digits = 5) # shows t statistic and p value 
    stargazer(europet.2, type="text", digits = 5)

TVandRadio = data.frame(tv = 21, radio = 75) 
        predict(europet.2, newdata = TVandRadio, interval ="confidence", level=0.90, digits = 7) * 90 # because there are 90 stores
```

Using this code I get the correct result for the fit however the upper and lower bounds of the Confidence Intervals are not correct. Is my approach wrong? How can an adjusted confidence interval if i multiply my results by 90?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you share your data please?

Comment: Thinking that you can estimate or believe condfidence intervals for sales across 90 stores based on sales at a single store is probably your main problem here.